# Error javascript function

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, dreamweaver

Hi I'm using Dreamweaver and it detected an error on line 78 to this javascript function. I can't spot the problem. Help me guys.

```
function FrontPage_Form1_Validator(theForm)
 {
   var checkOK = "0123456789-.,";
   var checkStr = theForm.theField.value;
   var allValid = true;
   var validGroups = true;
   var decPoints = 0;
   var allNum = "";
   for (i = 0;  i < checkStr.length;  i++)
{
  ch = checkStr.charAt(i);
  for (j = 0;  j < checkOK.length;  j++)
  if (ch = = checkOK.charAt(j))                 //------This is line 78------//
    break;                              
  if (j = = checkOK.length)
{
  allValid = false;
  break;
}
  if (ch = = ".")
{
  ....
   //will cut code here since it's not letting me post with so much code.
```

Comment: = = is not valid. should be ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space between the equal signs in your conditional.

Change `= =` to `==`.